# Cross-Check multidimensional integral

Tags: integration, definite-integrals, numerical-methods

I was asked to compute the value of 
$$
I_6=\int_{-\infty}^{\infty}dx_1\int_{-\infty}^{\infty}dx_2\int_{-\infty}^{\infty}dx_3\int_{-\infty}^{\infty}dx_4\int_{-\infty}^{\infty}dx_5 e^{-(x_1^2+x_2^2+x_3^2+x_4^2+x_5^2)} g(x_1,x_2,x_3,x_4,x_5)
$$
where
$$
g(x_1,x_2,x_3,x_4,x_5)=x_3^2\cos(x_4)\sin(x_5^2)+x_3^2(1+x_1)(1-x_4)+\cos^2(x_4)x_5^2
$$

I've calculate it using Monte-Carlo with importance sampling (assuming that $\{x_1,x_2,x_3,x_4,x_5\}$ are distributed with a $N(0,1)$) and I get $I_6 \approx 16.9456321457$.

My question is how can I cross-check this value (or, in general, any multidimensional integral)? 
I've tried some programs (such as Wolfram Alpha or Symbolab) and none of them works

Comment: Have tried solving analytically?

Comment: In general, a 5 dimension integral is not an esay thing to do analytically

Comment: This specific integral looks doable.

Comment: Maybe it's, I haven't tried it yet. Whatever, my question is about any free program that can compute it's value

Comment: You already know that this integral can be interpreted in terms of standard normal distribution. How about pushing that direction?

Comment: Also $\{x_1,\cdots,x_5\}$ are not distributed as $\mathcal{N}(0,1)$. They are distributed as $\mathcal{N}(0,\frac{1}{2})$.

Comment: Mathematica provides the exact result $$I_6= \frac{\pi ^{5/2} \left(3 e+1+(2 e)^{3/4} \sin \left(\frac{\pi }{8}\right)\right)}{4 e}\approx 16.921...$$